# How to prevent insert row duplicate value in a column and equal the any value

Tags: oracle

I have table

```
TABLE1(
 id number (primary key),
 IDAccount number,
 status char(10))
```

Table can have 2 row duplicate (IDAccount, status) with status=disable as well as

```
id     IDAccount     status
1       100          DISABLE
2       100          DISABLE
```

But, mustn't have 2 row duplicate (IDAccount, status) with status=enable as well as:

```
id     IDAccount     status
3       200          ENABLE
4       200          ENABLE // DON'T ALLOW
```

How I can do it ?
Thanks.

Comment: And what if one row has 'ENABLE' and another has 'DISABLE' (with the same id) Are NULL values possible for status(they are, if I look at your table definition), are other values than 'ENABLE'  and  'DISABLE' possible for status?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with a partial index. A bit complicated in Oracle because it doesn't allow a `where` clause in the `create index` statement (as e.g. Postgres does).

But you can still trick Oracle in only indexing a sub-set of the rows by exploiting the fact that entries where all index columns are null are not put into the index. So you create a a unique index on an expression that is only not-null if the status is `'ENABLE'`:

```
create unique index ix_only_one_enabled
  on table1 ( case when status = 'ENABLE' then idaccount else null end);
```

The expression will yield `null` for all rows where the status is something else than `enable` and those rows won't be put into the index. Which in turn means than only the IDACCOUNT values for rows are put into the index where the status is `ENABLE`

Note that `'enable'` and `'ENABLE'` are two different values for Oracle. You probably also want a check constraint on your column to make sure you only put uppercase values in there (or use a trigger),

---

Unrelated but: you most probably do **not** want to use `CHAR(10)` but `VARCHAR(10)` due to the padding that happens when using the dreaded `char` data type.

Comment: Alternatively: `… ( nullif(idaccount, 'DISABLE') )` (same effect, just more concise).

Comment: `You probably also want a check constraint on your column to make sure you only put uppercase values in there` – or, in fact, a check constraint limiting the acceptable values to just `ENABLE` and `DISABLE` (if that matches the requirements, of course).